# How can I get programs to run as root again using the sudo <app_name> command?

Tags: 16.04, sudo, root, ubuntu-mate

I think I some how managed to mess up my su settings and now, I've been unable to run programs as root.

Take virtualbox for instance, I use the `sudo virtualbox` command to run virtual box as root. On the top bar, I used to see "virtualbox is running as superuser" now, it no longer runs as superuser.

Please help me resolve this issue and thanks in advance.

PS: This is on Ubuntu mate 16.04

Comment: You may have caused the virtual machine file to be owned by `root`. Perhaps it is enough to do `sudo chown username:username virtual-machine-file`.

Comment: @Jos I think I also added root to sudo by accident

Comment: Why would you run virtualbox as root?

Comment: @mikewhatever I need virtualbox to run as root for cuckoo sandbox to recognise my vm.